# Can my two cities send resources at the same time?

Tags: simcity-2013

In this region I claimed two lands and built up two cities and both produce the materials needed by the Great Works. I pressed that power button in Great Works tab with both cities and some resources were sent to the Great Work, but the question is, are the resources being sent from both cities or just the one I loaded?

In other words if I load another city in the same region would the resource keep going to the Great Work or it will stop?

Answer (score 1):

It's going to stop.

If you are in 1 city, it's only going to send resources from the city you are currently working on / viewing at that moment.

So if City 1 is sending Oil, and City 2 is sending Alloy for example. When City 1 is loaded you will only be sending Oil and the Alloy will stop until you load City 2.

Comment: Is this Single-player mode only? Or it applies to multi-player as well?